# Check if at least 1 checkbox is ticked in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, post, checkbox

I have 4 checkboxes and a user is required to tick 1 to continue(but may tick more).  So I made 4 checkboxes:

```
    I have blue skin
    <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" name="skin" value="Yes" /><br>
    I have blue hair
    <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" name="hair" value="Yes" /><br>
    I have blue eyes
    <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" name="eyes" value="Yes" /><br>
    I have blue teeth
    <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" name="teeth" value="Yes" /><br>
```

I am looking to store this data.  But first of all, I confirm that at least one of these is checked.

```
if(isset($_POST['sent']) && !(isset($_POST['skin']) || isset($_POST['hair']) || isset($_POST['eyes']) || isset($_POST['teeth'])))
```

I am not sure this is the best way to achieve this, as I want to store a list of all of these.  I am thinking the best way is to use an array.

```
    I have blue skin
    <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" name="blue[]" value="skin" /><br>
```

And to store this in a text field having imploded it.  Being new, I am unsure how to achieve this and the tutorials I am reading are somewhat confusing.  Would doing it this way allow me to check instead if the array was empty(rather than 4 seperated isset?).  And how would I handle the array using $_POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did the following(a lot of poking around got it working).

```
I have blue skin
    <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" name="blue[]" value="skin" /><br>
```

All 4 using the same method.  Then...

```
if(isset($_POST['sent']) && empty($_POST['blue'])) {
 $bluedata = mysql_escape_string(implode(",",$_POST['blue']));
}
```

Then I wrote that string to the database.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `name="appearance[skin]"`, `name="appearance[hair]"` and so on, then check
`if(empty($_POST['appearance']))` or not. If it is empty, then no checkboxes were selected.

You can then access `$_POST['appearance']['skin']` and so on, or use
`foreach($_POST['appearance'] as $attribute=>$value)` to iterate through the selection.

Comment: If no checkbox was clicked, `$_POST['appearance']` should not exist at all, i.e. is not set instead of an empty array. But the check `empty( $_POST['appearance'] )` would be true in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of the fields into an array and then loop through that array and set a flag:

```
$checkboxes = array('skin', 'hair', 'eyes', 'teeth');

$oneTicked = false;
foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox)
{
    if(!empty($_POST[$checkbox]))
    {
        $oneTicked = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then you can just check if `$oneTicked` is true.

Comment: Causes undefined index notices for every variable that's not sent. Instead, consider only saving the key names in the `$checkboxes` array, then check `if(empty($_POST[$checkbox]))`. Also consider `break`ing out of the loop when one match is found, since it's not necessary to continue searching.